# Vitest: can't fetch a local file

Tags: javascript, typescript, fetch-api, vitest

I'm trying to get a test for fetching a local file.

I've got a YAML configuration file.

In production, the name of the file could be changed. The filename comes over the web socket.

In production, it works, but I want to test the code with a dummy file. The problem is this error message from the fetch call:

`TypeError: Failed to parse URL from customStyle.test.yaml`

Is it even possible to use `fetch` in JavaScript on local files?

The `customStyle.test.yaml` is in the same directory as the code file.

**customStyle.ts**

```js
const load = async (fileName: string) => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch(fileName,{
        headers : {
          'Content-Type': 'application/yaml',
          'Accept': 'application/yaml'
        }
      })
      const yamlString = await res.text()

      const data = YAML.parse(yamlString)
      ...
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Failed to read style config: ", error)
    }
  }
```

**customStyle.test.ts**

```js
describe("from local custom style file", () => {
  it("fontSize has change", () => {
    (async () => await style.load("customStyle.test.yaml"))();
     ...
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience that is not possible. vitest uses jsdom and jsdom doesn't care about creating a serve for file interaction

But instead you can use `node.js` API or `deno` or `bun` or whatever to read the file:

### Case 1: just call `fetch` in `test`

```js
import { readFile } from "fs/promises"

const load = async (fileName: string) => {
    try {
      const yamlString = await readFile(`${__dirname}/${fileName}`, "utf8")

      const data = YAML.parse(yamlString)
      ...
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Failed to read style config: ", error)
    }
}
```

### Case2: If the `fetch` calls are called inside your code (not test code) you must use code injection tactics like this:

`patch-fetch.ts`

```js
/// <reference path="../node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts" />

import { readFile } from 'fs/promises';
import { resolve } from 'path';

function toArrayBuffer(buffer: Buffer) {
  const arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(buffer.length);
  const view = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
  for (let i = 0; i < buffer.length; ++i) view[i] = buffer[i];

  return arrayBuffer;
}
class ResponseFake {
  constructor(public buffer: Buffer) {}

  async json() {
    return JSON.parse(this.buffer.toString());
  }
  async text() {
    return this.buffer.toString();
  }
  async arrayBuffer() {
    return toArrayBuffer(this.buffer);
  }
}

const { fetch } = self;
Object.assign(self, {
  fetch(url: string) {
    if (url.includes('://')) return fetch(url);
  
    return readFile(resolve(__dirname, url)).then(
      (buffer) => new ResponseFake(buffer)
    );
  }
})
```

then before every file test that uses `fetch` in the code call `import './patch-fetch'` in the first line and it will work

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-drahmf?file=src%2FloadJSON.ts,vitest.config.ts,src%2FloadJSON.spec.ts,src%2Ftest.json,package.json,tsconfig.json,src%2Fpatch-fetch.ts&terminal=dev

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I Tried fs from node.
But this is vite answer:

`Module "fs" has been externalized for browser compatibility. Cannot access "fs.readFileSync" in client code`

Comment: are you calling it in the code that needs to run the test? if so we need to inject a function for it to work

Comment: I just found out, to have pollyfill the node modules.
In testcase fs works.
But vite don't deploy node modules.

Comment: @Manuel no need to do that I understand your case and have updated the answer

Comment: thank you very much. This solution works fine!
Now i have to study this how it works  ;-)